# Broken references in a cloned git repo

Tags: git, nuget

Many times when I clone a git repo most or all of the references are broken. The dlls are not there. I searched and found nothing about the problem. I feel like it has something to do with nuget.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a `.nuget` folder in the repo and it will contain `nuget.exe`. Some repos include a script that will do the work of restoring the missing packages. But you can also do it manually by issuing the following command to nuget:

```
nuget restore "path\to\.sln"
```

Answer (score 1):

The dll are not there most probably because they are ignored: you should have a .gitignpre with a *.dll in it.

That means you need to run nuget in order to download the right dependencies (dll): this is a declarative approach, which means you only version the nuget file (very small) instead of the dlls (much larger).